# Filereader, file and javascript

Tags: javascript, file, 3ds

so here's my situation. I have my website and would like to know if it's possible to call the "FileReader" or "new file" methods to display a 3ds object in a specific canvas when the page is loading  ?

Comment: File methods in JavaScript run on the client machine and therefore reference the file system there, so I doubt that's what you want to do (unless every visitor will have the file in question on their PC in the same place).  You'd most likely need to reference the 3ds file via a URL that points to the server.

Comment: Do you have a [mcve] you can add to your question?

Comment: /* HTML side */

<div id="top">
</div>
<div id="left">
 <div id="menu"></div>
</div>
<canvas id="example"></canvas>

/* js and server side: I need a object file */

var file= new File(['UrlOfMyFile.3ds'], "file.3ds");
Process(file);